# XQuery and idref

Tags: xml, database, xquery, xml-database

A real XQuery-beginner question, but I can't seem to get around my issue.

I have an XML database videos.xml, in which actors and movies are stored as nodes (I think?)

The actors all have separate IDs, but they're not stored as attributes but as something else (Is there perhaps some built-in attribute for IDs?). The movies all have one or several actorRef attributes referencing actor-IDs.

What I want to query for now is all the movies that are referencing a certain actor-id. Let's say Keanu Reeves has ID "001", then we'd want to find all movies that are referencing this ID -> e.g. Matrix and The Devil's Advocate. Is there some built-in function for this?

Comment: Please provide examples of your XML and what you've already tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the commenters that more is needed, but you seem to be looking for the family of functions, [`fn:id()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-id), [`fn:idref()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-idref), and new to version 3.1 of the XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators specification, [`fn:element-with-id()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-element-with-id). Here are some illustrations taken from the spec:

```
let $emp :=
    <employee xml:id="ID21256">
        <empnr>E21256</empnr>
        <first>John</first>
        <last>Brown</last>
    </employee>
```

The expression `id('ID21256')/name()` returns `"employee"`. (The `xml:id` attribute has the `is-id` property, so the employee element is selected.).

The expression `element-with-id('E21256')/name()` also returns `"employee"`. (Assuming the `empnr` element is given the type `xs:ID` as a result of schema validation, the element will have the `is-id` property and is therefore selected.)

The expression `idref('ID21256')` would return any element or attribute referencing the `employee` element. (Assuming that the referencing node is given the type `xs:IDREF` or `xs:IDREFS` as a result of schema validation, the node will have the `is-idrefs` property.)